# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'angular-signature-pad'

Tags: angular6

I got below error, try adding signature to my angular 6 project

```
node module : - angular-signature-pad
error: -  ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts(5,41): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular-signature-pad'.
```

Comment: I believe you want to use Angular2-signaturepad https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-signaturepad.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue in the angular6 project. Does anyone have a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things to check?

1) Did you install the package ?

```
npm install angular-signature-pad --save
```

2) Import the package in app module.

```
import { AngularSignaturePadModule } from 'angular-signature-pad';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    AngularSignaturePadModule.forRoot()
  ]
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Maybe possibility, It may not be working in angular 4 plus.
https://github.com/BioPhoton/angular-signature-pad/issues/2

Comment: Tried in Angular 5. The package is indeed installed and I can locate it in the nodemodules. But the error still persists.

Comment: I have angular 14 and it doesn't work, ..

Comment: I guess it's time to look for an alternative. It does not work at all on Angular 15.

Answer (score 0):

try updating node.js to version 16+
or
update angular cli

ng update @angular/cli @angular/core

Answer (score 0):

[Nimish goel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51158279/5211833) did not work for me, so I added this to the import

```
import { AngularSignaturePadModule } from 'angular-signature-pad/angular-signature-pad';
```